# AngularJs can't read dynamically set attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to be able to create a angularjs directive that in the end creates a HighCharts graph from the elements attributes. I have a directive working but any dynamically set attributes are returning undefined. In the end i want all the attributes on the element to be sent to a $http request as params.

I have tried using the $observe method and it does not seem to work, also i would like the attributes to be anything and not predefined.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F52SF/ and code below of directive:

```
myApp.directive('example', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log('Log1:', attrs.exampleId);
            attrs.$observe('exampleAttr', function () {
                console.log('Log2:', attrs.exampleId);
            });

            var data = {};
            for(var i in attrs){
                var t = Object.prototype.toString.call( attrs[i] );
                if(t !== '[object Object]' && t != '[object Function]') data[i] = attrs[i];
            } 
            console.log(data);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example code there are couple of mistakes/improvements:

1. You're mixing exampleAttr and exampleId
2. Its better to read value passed to callback of $observe function:

   ```
   attrs.$observe('exampleAttr', function(newValue) {
       /* use newValue here instead of attrs.exampleAttr */
   });
   ```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F52SF/1/